# Почему не работает программа?

Tags: c++

Почему не работает программа? после выполнения операции "do...while" программа прекращает свою работу..

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int a, b, gcd;

    do {
        cout<<"enter number a and b (so that a anb b is not 0):"<<endl;
        cin>>a>>b;
    } while (a == 0 && b == 0);

    do {
        if (a > b) {
            a = a % b;

        } else if (b > a) {
            b = b % a;
        }
    } while (a != 0 || b != 0);

    cout<<"greatest common divisor of the given numbers = "<<a+b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: прекращает работу, после выполнения 2-ой операции "do...while"

Comment: пожалуйста, запустите программу в отладчике, если есть какие ошибки - приведите тут их текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представим, что после очередной итерации `a` таки 0, а `b` ну, скажем, 10.

```
a != 0 || b != 0
```

совершенно истинно - `b` не равно 0, так что выходим на следующую итерацию и начинаем делить на 0...

Тут вам нужно

```
a != 0 && b != 0
```

А вот в первом цикле как раз нужно

```
a == 0 || b == 0
```

чтобы не принимало даже одного нуля, а не оба :)